# Hash::make doesn't generate same value for same input

Tags: php, hash, laravel-5

I have this code `$pass` and `$confirm_pass` have the same input but after hashing have different values.

```
$pass = '12345678';

$Password = **Hash::make**($pass);
//after hashing: $2y$10$acEYvpJSbaftfrabwBCNruCW32lkJejBdT92jQVSNIMeL7gtPvseK

$confirm_pass = '12345678';

$Password_Confirmation = **Hash::make**($confirm_pass);
//after hashing: $2y$10$HcCvNiwlZAUnt9RgQuXJ1.06H8ri8HdUa3tzbCCe9jvs3PtBHWGJK
```

and I get this line after validation :

> {"password":["**The password confirmation does not match**."]}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Hash::make()` will not generate the same hash even when the password is the same, because every hash is individually salted, so every output from Hash::Make() is different.

As Nishant says, you need to use `Hash::check()` to validate the hash

Comment: And the comparison of password and password-confirmation should be done _before_ hashing.

Comment: I want to add that this is done on purpose and makes the hashing function *a lot* more secure.

Answer (score 0):

From laravel security docs I found below code,

to create hashed password, use below code

```
$password = Hash::make($pass);
```

and to verify it

```
if (Hash::check($pass, $password))
{
    // The passwords match...
}
```

further documentations can be found from
http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security